# Ember Js not authenticating with Devise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, authentication, ember.js, devise

My ember js app is not authenticating the session correctly. It will post to the data base correctly but will not authenticate the session. I am using rails 4, ember-simple-auth1.1.0 and ember 2.5

Rails Session Controller

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :html, :json

def create
 super do |user|
  if request.format.json?
     data = {
      token: user.authentication_token,
      email: user.email
    }
    render json: data, status: 201  and return
    end
  end
 end
end
```

Ember login controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

  actions: {
    authenticate() {
      let { identification, password } = this.getProperties('identification', 'password');
      this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:devise', identification, password)
      .then(() =>{
        this.transitionToRoute('posts')
      })
      .catch((reason) => {
        this.set('errorMessage', reason.error || reason);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Login.hbs

```
{{#modal-dialog close="goBackToList"}}
  {{login-form }}
{{/modal-dialog}}
```

login-form.hbs

```
    <form {{action "authenticate" on="submit"}}>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="identification">Login</label>
        {{input class="form-control" value=identification placeholder="Enter Login"}}
      </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      {{input class="form-control" value=password type="password" placeholder="Enter Password"}}
    </div>

      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>


    {{#if errorMessage}}
      {{errorMessage}}
    {{/if}}
```

The entire project can be found at https://github.com/nickharvey27/Akira

Comment: How do you know the authentication failed? I mean do you get an error?

Comment: No i do not get an error but when I try to use the helper   `{{#if session.isAuthenticated}}`
 The content woulnt show up and the content in the else block will.